# Flutter: How to Change tooltip name of "paste" on textField to device's language

Tags: dart, tooltip, flutter

When i go to copy or paste on textfield, the tooltip is always on english language, and my device is on Pt-Br. How can i change or fix that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add flutter_localizations to your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

In your `MaterialApp`:

```
return MaterialApp(
  ...
  locale: const Locale('de'), // change to locale you want. not all locales are supported
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
);
```

Comment: https://flutter.io/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization supportedLocales: [ const Locale('ko', 'KR') ] works for me, thanks

Comment: woops it works for android only, so i had to add CustomLocalizations for iOS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53752290/6228111