# How to change CupertinoDatePicker display language?

Tags: flutter

I'm follow Flutter docs to show CupertinoDatePicker. But language alway is English. Please show me how to change this.

Here my code:

```
void _showDatePicker(BuildContext context, bool isYou) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return CupertinoDatePicker(
            onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime value) {
              setState(() {
                if (isYou) {
                  _dateOfBirth = value;
                } else {
                  _dateOfBirthAnother = value;
                }
              });
            },

            initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
            mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
            maximumYear: 2018,
            minimumYear: 1950,
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: i found this solution, and it works perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066397/12172908

Comment: This tutorial is all you need: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add your required languages to your MaterialApp (or CupertinoApp) configuration. 
Like this:

```
return MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: [
      // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    supportedLocales: [
      const Locale('en', 'US'), // English
      const Locale('de', 'DE'), // German
      // ... other locales the app supports
    ],  <the rest of your configuration> );
```

This should do it.

Don't forget the imports:

```
import 'package:toothscout/GermanCupertinoLocalizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

Also, Cupertino Widgets are not fully localized (yet).
But you can write your own localization configuration classes and add them below the line "DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate" in my code.

For example, my custom german localization that i had to create to use CupertinoDatePicker in german language looks like this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';


class _CupertinoLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<CupertinoLocalizations> {
  const _CupertinoLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => locale.languageCode == 'de';

  @override
  Future<CupertinoLocalizations> load(Locale locale) => GermanCupertinoLocalizations.load(locale);

  @override
  bool shouldReload(_CupertinoLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;

  @override
  String toString() => 'DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate(de_DE)';
}

/// US English strings for the cupertino widgets.
class GermanCupertinoLocalizations implements CupertinoLocalizations {
  /// Constructs an object that defines the cupertino widgets' localized strings
  /// for US English (only).
  ///
  /// [LocalizationsDelegate] implementations typically call the static [load]
  /// function, rather than constructing this class directly.
  const GermanCupertinoLocalizations();

  static const List<String> _shortWeekdays = <String>[
    'Mo',
    'Di',
    'Mi',
    'Do',
    'Fr',
    'Sa',
    'So',
  ];

  static const List<String> _shortMonths = <String>[
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mär',
    'Apr',
    'Mai',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Okt',
    'Nov',
    'Dez',
  ];

  static const List<String> _months = <String>[
    'Januar',
    'Februar',
    'März',
    'April',
    'Mai',
    'Juni',
    'Juli',
    'August',
    'September',
    'Oktober',
    'November',
    'Dezember',
  ];



  @override
  String datePickerYear(int yearIndex) => yearIndex.toString();

  @override
  String datePickerMonth(int monthIndex) => _months[monthIndex - 1];

  @override
  String datePickerDayOfMonth(int dayIndex) => dayIndex.toString();

  @override
  String datePickerHour(int hour) => hour.toString();

  @override
  String datePickerHourSemanticsLabel(int hour) => hour.toString() + " Uhr";

  @override
  String datePickerMinute(int minute) => minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0');

  @override
  String datePickerMinuteSemanticsLabel(int minute) {
    if (minute == 1)
      return '1 Minute';
    return minute.toString() + ' Minuten';
  }

  @override
  String datePickerMediumDate(DateTime date) {
    return '${_shortWeekdays[date.weekday - DateTime.monday]} '
        '${_shortMonths[date.month - DateTime.january]} '
        '${date.day.toString().padRight(2)}';
  }

  @override
  DatePickerDateOrder get datePickerDateOrder => DatePickerDateOrder.mdy;

  @override
  DatePickerDateTimeOrder get datePickerDateTimeOrder => DatePickerDateTimeOrder.date_time_dayPeriod;

  @override
  String get anteMeridiemAbbreviation => 'AM';

  @override
  String get postMeridiemAbbreviation => 'PM';

  @override
  String get alertDialogLabel => 'Info';

  @override
  String timerPickerHour(int hour) => hour.toString();

  @override
  String timerPickerMinute(int minute) => minute.toString();

  @override
  String timerPickerSecond(int second) => second.toString();

  @override
  String timerPickerHourLabel(int hour) => hour == 1 ? 'Stunde' : 'Stunden';

  @override
  String timerPickerMinuteLabel(int minute) => 'Min';

  @override
  String timerPickerSecondLabel(int second) => 'Sek';

  @override
  String get cutButtonLabel => 'Ausschneiden';

  @override
  String get copyButtonLabel => 'Kopieren';

  @override
  String get pasteButtonLabel => 'Einfügen';

  @override
  String get selectAllButtonLabel => 'Alles auswählen';

  /// Creates an object that provides US English resource values for the
  /// cupertino library widgets.
  ///
  /// The [locale] parameter is ignored.
  ///
  /// This method is typically used to create a [LocalizationsDelegate].
  static Future<CupertinoLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    return SynchronousFuture<CupertinoLocalizations>(const GermanCupertinoLocalizations());
  }

  /// A [LocalizationsDelegate] that uses [DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.load]
  /// to create an instance of this class.
  static const LocalizationsDelegate<CupertinoLocalizations> delegate = _CupertinoLocalizationsDelegate();
}
```

Comment: Noo, you don't need all this work. Just add your Specific Localization and the datepicker will always be like your Locale

Comment: flutter_cupertino_localizations is the correct solution, check @malibayram91 answer

Answer (score 2):

firstly you should add this to pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1

flutter_localizations: 
  sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to the problem, had to add fallback to localizationsDelegates, as follows:

```
localizationsDelegates: [ ..... const FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate(), ]
```

And the delegate:

```
class FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate {
    const FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate();

    @override
    bool isSupported(Locale locale) => true;

    @override
    Future load(Locale locale) =>
    DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.load(locale);

    @override
    bool shouldReload(FallbackCupertinoLocalisationsDelegate old) => false;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

This solves the problem.

```
MaterialApp(
    ...
    localizationsDelegates: [
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,,l
    ])
```