# How to localise CupertinoDatePicker in flutter and getxcontroller

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

During my search I found some regular solution when no GetXcontroller included, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53752290/19815795

Taking above as inspiration, I created some code for my GetMaterialApp:

```
GetMaterialApp(
        theme: AppTheme(),
        translations: Language(),
        locale: getCurrentLocale(),
        fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
        supportedLocales: [ // Here I got error, maybe because I am using GetXController
        const Locale('en', 'US'),
        const Locale('de', 'DE'),
        const Locale('fr', 'FR'),
        const Locale('zh', 'CN'),
        const Locale('ar', 'QA'),
        const Locale('es', 'ES'),
          ],
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          DefaultCupertinoLocalizationsLocal.delegate, // code from above link
        ],

        home: SettingScreen(),
        );
```

But as result, the CupertinoPicker didn't recognise my local language, still using default english, does anyone know how to localise CupertinoDatePicker in flutter and getxcontroller, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding those to `localizationsDelegates`:

```
  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
```